# Self-signed client certificate and TRestClient component in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, rest, ssl, indy, delphi-xe7

I'm building multi-platform client app using FireMonkey which will communicate with server that will be also developed in house, so we were looking for using self signed certificate in this scenario.

According to this article: [SSL / HTTPS on different platforms with TIdHTTP and TRESTClient](http://www.monien.net/delphi-xe5-ssl-https-on-different-platforms-with-tidhttp-and-trestclient/), it seems that TRestClient has support for SSL out of the box and there is no need to assign IO Handler like with TidHTTP. Problem is that I can't find a way to assign self signed certificate to TRestClient the way you could do it with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL component. Also, TRestClient.HTTPClient seems to not have published IOHandler property the way Indy's HTTP had.

My question is this:
Is there a way to provide self-signed certificate to TRestClient component in Delphi XE7 and how?

Comment: Sorry the question was not clear for me: do you want to use client-side SSL certificates, to identify the clients?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: I think you have to use TidHTTP straight.